# Activate Conda Environment From Script

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, pytorch, environment, slurm

I am using a server that runs on slurm. It requires the use of scripts to launch jobs. Particularly, I have to use the following command:

```
sbatch script.sh
```

Inside this script, I have to specify a couple of things, including the conda environment I'm using, which I do in the following way:

```
source activate /path.../envs/
python job_to_run.py
```

The process keeps crushing because it fails to load Pytorch (even if it loads Numpy, for example). The problem is that Pytorch is installed in /env/lib, and it has no problem loading it if I run the job without a script, using the command

```
python job_to_run.py
```

directly from the command line.

How can I solve this problem? Thank You!

Comment: have you tried using `conda activate env_name` instead of `source activate ...`?

Comment: I did, still does not work